# Retrieve headers from a financial time-series object

Tags: matlab

I have code that creates a portfolio in matlab by merging two time series. How do I retrieve a vector of Headers for the funds such that I get a vector with the fund names from 'Port'?

```
Fund1ts=fints(Fund1Dates,Fund1Data,'Fund1');
Fund2ts=fints(Fund2Dates,Fund2Data,'Fund2');

%CREATE PORTFOLIO
Port=merge(Fund1ts,Fund2ts,'DateSetMethod','Intersection');
```

If you look at Port in the Command Window they are present. However if you open Port from Workspace Window then only the data exists hence my problem in retrieving it.
Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like nonsense to me. Is Port a class? cell? object? Can you do `class(Port)` and tell us what it is? Who wrote `merge`? Can you provide the code?

Comment: [`merge`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/merge.html) is a function of the [`Financial Toolbox`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/index.html).

Comment: @Memming You can see from my code that Port is an object that is created. fints and merge are inbuilt Matlab functions. The Merge function creates a fints object therefore class(Port) returns ans= fints. FundXDates and FundXData are simply single columns of data (class double) (as required by fints). Not sure how else I can simplify this further for you. All I want is the headers at the top of Port but as it is fints it is not obvious. Not fair to vote the question down because the functions are not familiar.

Comment: Does it work like a cell: `Port.dates`?

Comment: @Schorsch Yes it does- I get a column of datenum values. Also if I input "Port" only I get all the dates and data with the headings {'dates:  (2384)'    'Fund1:  (2384)'    'Fund2:  (2384)'}. It is these headings Fund1, Fund2 that I am after. These are not present in the saved file in the "Workspace" window.

Comment: Try this (if it works, I'll post it as an answer - but I don't have the Financial Toolbox and don't want to prematurely reply): `names = fieldnames(Port)` Ideally, `names` would be a cell containing your headers

Comment: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/finance/data-extractionu.html This looks like it will be useful - `fnames = fieldnames(tsobj, srsnameonly)` particularly.

Comment: Ah, I see. My bad. I have no experience with the Financial toolbox, that's why. It would have been nice if you indicated that in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Hugh Nolan also suggested in a comment, this should get you the names you are after:

```
fnames = fieldnames(Port, 1)
```

From the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/fieldnames.html):

> fnames = fieldnames(tsobj, srsnameonly) returns field names depending upon the setting of srsnameonly. If srsnameonly is 0, the function returns all field names, including the common fields: desc, freq, dates, and times. If srsnameonly is set to 1, fieldnames returns only the data series in fnames.

Hence the `1` in the code-snippet above. It will return only `Fund1` and `Fund2`.

**Edit**

It appears that there are **two** functions called `fieldnames` in Matlab:

- The 'standard' function [`fieldnames`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fieldnames.html):

> names = fieldnames(s)
>   names = fieldnames(obj)
>   names = fieldnames(obj,'-full')

- The function [`fieldnames`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/fieldnames.html) which is part of the [`Financial Toolbox`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/index.html):

> fnames = fieldnames(tsobj)
>   fnames = fieldnames(tsobj, srsnameonly)

If called with one input argument, they both operate similarly. However, for future readers of this answer: The particular answer given above works only for the `Financial Toolbox`-version of the function.

Comment: @EitanT : Not sure if it's off-topic, but would you happen to know where I could find out how Matlab actually differentiates between two functions that have the same name?